# How set person field in Flow: Send HTTP Request to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I've been playing with Flow: Send HTTP Request to SharePoint to create items in a list. Everything works great until I include the Person field: Assigned To.

error 400: A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of a navigation property

Tried claims, display name, email...

[image]

Looking at the list item XML I see **Assigned_x0020_ToId**, so I guess I need to pass the numeric ID of the person. Do I need a step prior to resolve the user or look up their id?

Once I figure out this issue I would like to move on to something more advanced, like creating a list item for each person in a multiple person column...

[image]

FYI, I would have just used the available Create Item but Flow seems to ignore site column lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I create a person or group column named “p1” in the list. And then I create the flow in the list and add the “send HTTP Request to SharePoint“ action in the flow.

To get the internal name of the person column, you could use the URL below and find the person column. And the value of the person column is not the user name, it is the code.

https://yoursite /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items

[image]

Then in the flow, I add the body like the picture below.
[image]

Comment: How did you get the value to set the StringID to?  ('28' in your example)

Comment: easiest way is to use 'Get User Profile (V2)' action for it.